# Is there a good utility for resizing application windows to preset sizes in OS X?

Tags: macos, window, applescript

I've been using the Better Touch Tool and Right Zoom to be able to maximize windows to full screen, and to resize windows to the center, or top right / left quarter of the screen. Those apps are pretty slick.

What I really want is a way to predefine some windows specs and then apply that to a window. For example, the window could be 1024 * 768, or maybe it could be 300px from each edge of the screen.

I know the green button is supposed to choose a nice size for the window but it doesn't always work and with some apps (like TextMate) I'd just prefer to have a preset size / position that I could use.

I could probably somehow use applescript, but at times it seems to take forever before it runs so a native app for this would be cooler.

Thoughts?

Comment: If AppleScript takes too long you're probably wrapping it in a service. It's Automator's fault, not AppleScript. Use FastScripts or the global scripts menu you can enable via AppleScript Editor's preferences.

Comment: @db - off topic, but what if I save applescript as an app and then add it to the toolbar of finder windows? seems like sometimes this takes several seconds before running.

Comment: Haven't experienced that yet. How does it perform with the scripts menu I suggested, and placing them in /Users/cwd/Library/Scripts/? I'm not on a Mac right now. Btw, skip the @ or get it right -- I didn't get notified at about your comment.

Comment: I'll try using the scripts menu. regarding the @, I didn't realize it actually notified when using it. Where is the documentation on that?

Comment: The Applescript runtime can take up to a few seconds to load, which causes a delay if you haven't run any scripts in a while. I'd say it's usually under a second though. And [How do comment @replies work? - Super User Meta](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2081/how-do-comment-replies-work).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### [Divvy](http://mizage.com/divvy/#divvyMac)

[image]

#### [Breeze](http://www.autumnapps.com/breeze/)

[image]

#### [Optimal Layout](http://most-advantageous.com/optimal-layout/)

[image]

#### AppleScripts for saving and restoring default dimensions

Save Bounds.scpt

```
try
    set text item delimiters to space
    tell application (path to frontmost application as text)
        set b to (bounds of window 1) as text
        set n to name
    end tell
    do shell script "a=" & quoted form of n & "
f=~/Notes/bounds.txt
touch \"$f\"
sed -i '' \"/^$a: /d\" \"$f\"
echo \"$a: " & b & "\" >> \"$f\""
end try
```

Restore Bounds.scpt

```
try
    tell application (path to frontmost application as text)
        set n to name
        set s to do shell script "sed -En s/^" & quoted form of n & "': (.*)/\\1/p' ~/Notes/bounds.txt"
        set bounds of window 1 to words of s
    end tell
end try
```

#### AppleScript for resizing windows to specific dimensions

```
try
        tell application "Finder" to set {0, 0, dtw, dth} to bounds of window of desktop
        tell application (path to frontmost application as text) to tell window 1
            set b to bounds
            set w to (item 3 of b) - (item 1 of b)
            set h to (item 4 of b) - (item 2 of b)
            set b to {dtw - w, (dth - h) / 2, dtw, dth - (dth - h) / 2}
            set bounds to b
        end tell
end try
```

Comment: Divvy's on sale today by the way, $2 on the App Store.